# How can we access other App's Shared prefs from my app using FileProvider programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-fileprovider

I want to read the shared preference of my 1st app in my 2nd App. What is the best possible way of doing it.

The MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE modes have been deprecated since API level 17.

We need some other better way.

Comment: Extend ContentProvider for app 1. App 2 can then query your provider.